# How to identify the current environment of ASP.NET, Staging or production from code Behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, connection-string, staging

I am generating a report using ASP.NET. The report has different names in staging and production. IF there is a way to get my current environment(staging or production), then using IF condition I can change the report name for staging and production. Kindly help me in finding the environment or connectionstring name from code behind.

Comment: For the connection string, look at ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings, otherwise you'll need to add a configuration item to define the installation type (staging or production)

Comment: Could you not simply add the information in question to a database table somewhere? And then you query that to see whether you are in production or staging?